# exporting JavaFX project to jar. file. error when loading FXML file

Tags: jar, javafx-8, fxml, ioexception

So I have this weird problem. Application works within eclipse project, but when I export project to jar. file and run it, then I get IOexception when loading one of fxml files.

Here is the exception:

```
javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
com/root/tomaszm/Countdown.fxml

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(Unknown Source)
    at com.controller.tomaszm.WrittenNumbersController.initializeStoperAndCountdown(WrittenNumbersController.java:162)
    at com.controller.tomaszm.WrittenNumbersController.initialize(WrittenNumbersController.java:114)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(Unknown Source)
    at com.model.tomaszm.ChangeTheRoot.initialize(ChangeTheRoot.java:68)
    at com.controller.tomaszm.MainRootController.fireUpTheFeature(MainRootController.java:103)
    at com.controller.tomaszm.MainRootController.access$0(MainRootController.java:96)
    at com.controller.tomaszm.MainRootController$MouseClickListCell$1.handle(MainRootController.java:147)
    at com.controller.tomaszm.MainRootController$MouseClickListCell$1.handle(MainRootController.java:1)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.postProcess(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.access$7900(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$141(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$38/1657033223.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.controller.tomaszm.CountdownController.initialize(CountdownController.java:63)
    ... 46 more
```

Tell me if You need some extra informations.

EDIT:
Ive found out that this is a problem with loading the font file that is in `source` folder `Files`:

```
try {
            Font registerFont = Font.loadFont(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("DS-DIGIT.ttf").openStream(), 30);
            labTime.setFont(registerFont);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            Dialogs.create().title("Exception").masthead(null).message("Couldnt load the font fxml!").showException(e1);
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I just dont get it why this code work within the project and causes some weird errors when I make a jar file. Is there any way I can load this font properly? Btw. I remember in early stages of project that I have build jar file with font in it, and it was working with no problem.... Im counfused here.

[image]

Comment: Where is the `DS-DIGIT.ttf` located?

Comment: @ItachiUchiha I have included the image.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't create the files within your code or copy them when you are building the project then it's clear that they are not in the build-folder.

So for example if you are using Ant for building your project then write a target that copies the ttf file to the same folder where your jar file will be created. As workaround you can copy it yourself to the same folder.

Comment: so, is there a way to create this font file within a project that I will have everything within a jar later and no extra files needed?

Comment: Sorry didn't hat time to look again but it seems that you already solved it in your own way :)

Answer (score 0):

So based on informtions from **Juce** I've been looking in the internet for solution how to include font into jar and then later use it. I've found this code:

```
InputStream istream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/resources/SerpentineBolditalic.ttf");
Font myFont = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, istream);
myFont = myFont.deriveFont(36.0f);
lblNewLabel.setFont(myFont);
```

however some of the code like `Font.TRUETYPE_FONT` seems do depreciated with current Java edition. So I had to make some changes and now everything seems to be working:

```
InputStream is = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/DS-DIGIT.TTF");
Font uniFont = Font.loadFont(is, 30);
labTime.setFont(uniFont);
```